# is there any code for bitwise and ipv6 address and network mask (prefix)?

Tags: c++, c, networking, ipv6

I want to ask about calculation of ipv6 network and host side.

For example, I have the IPv6 address `2001:470:1f15:1bcd:34::41` and prefix `96`.

Do you know a easy way to do bitwise `and` between IPv6 address and prefix?

According to IPv4:

```
192.168.1.2  255.255.255.0  network : 192.168.1.0
```

So simple.

I want to do the same thing to IPv6 address. But IPv6 address is 16 bytes, so you can't use `unsigned int` for that.

Is there any API to do this? Or should I use arrays?

Comment: If you write 255.255.255.0 as /24 then the bit fiddling is almost identical.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't be using `unsigned int` for IPv4 either; you should be using `uint32_t` (or a typedef of it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the functions `in6_addr_mask` and `in6_addr_start` from [**`in6calc.c`**](https://github.com/emden-norfolk/cidrl/blob/b2452e8/in6calc.c).

Example usage:

```c
struct in6_addr addr, mask, start;
char addr_buffer[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN] = "2001:470:1f15:1bcd:34::41";
uint8_t bits = 96; 

inet_pton(AF_INET6, addr_buffer, &addr);

in6_addr_mask(&mask, bits); // Mask
in6_addr_start(&start, &addr, &mask); // Bitwise &

inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &start, addr_buffer, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
printf("Network:    %s\n", addr_buffer);
```

Yields:

```
Network:    2001:470:1f15:1bcd:34::
```

Answer (score 2):

Calculate mask from prefix length:

```
struct sockaddr_in6 netmask;
for (long i = prefixLength, j = 0; i > 0; i -= 8, ++j)
  netmask.sin6_addr.s6_addr[ j ] = i >= 8 ? 0xff
                                    : (ULONG)(( 0xffU << ( 8 - i ) ) & 0xffU );
```

Apply netmask to address, I derived this from [`inet_lnaof`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_lnaof).

```
bool
inet6_lnaof (
        struct in6_addr* restrict       dst,
        const struct in6_addr* restrict src,
        const struct in6_addr* restrict netmask
        )
{
        bool has_lna = FALSE;

        assert (NULL != dst);
        assert (NULL != src);
        assert (NULL != netmask);

        for (unsigned i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
                dst->s6_addr[i] = src->s6_addr[i] & netmask->s6_addr[i];
                has_lna |= (0 != (src->s6_addr[i] & !netmask->s6_addr[i]));
        }

        return has_lna;
}
```

Comment: Memory corruption alert!  Hint:  How many times does your loop iterate if prefixLength is, say, 3?

Comment: @JdeBP Tested in multiples of 8 only (tm) :-)

Answer (score 2):

OK, I did this in C rather than C++, but it should work. Also, it uses [`bswap_64`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/bswap_16.3.html) which is AFAIK a GNU extension so may not work on everything.

It seems to be very quick on amd64, and faster than the current solution Yasar has come up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>

#if defined __GNUC__ && __GNUC__ >= 2
#include <byteswap.h>
#else
#error "Sorry, you need GNU for this"
#endif

struct split
{
  uint64_t start;
  uint64_t end;
};

void ipv6_prefix (unsigned char *masked, unsigned char *packed, int prefix)
{
  struct split parts;
  uint64_t mask = 0;
  unsigned char *p = masked;

  memset(masked, 0, sizeof(struct in6_addr));
  memcpy(&parts, packed, sizeof(parts));

  if (prefix <= 64)
  {
    mask = bswap_64(bswap_64(parts.start) & ((uint64_t) (~0) << (64 - prefix)));
    memcpy(masked, &mask, sizeof(uint64_t));
    return;
  }

  prefix -= 64;

  memcpy(masked, &(parts.start), sizeof(uint64_t));
  p += sizeof(uint64_t);
  mask = bswap_64(bswap_64(parts.end) & (uint64_t) (~0) << (64 - prefix));
  memcpy(p, &mask, sizeof(uint64_t));
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  unsigned char packed[sizeof(struct in6_addr)];
  unsigned char masked[sizeof(struct in6_addr)];
  char buf[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN], *p;
  int prefix = 56;

  if (argc < 2)
    return 1;

  if ((p = strchr(argv[1], '/')))
  {
    *p++ = '\0';
    prefix = atoi(p);
  }

  inet_pton(AF_INET6, argv[1], packed);

  ipv6_prefix(masked, packed, prefix);

  inet_ntop(AF_INET6, masked, buf, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
  printf("prefix = %s/%d\n", buf, prefix);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just tried it on an i686 virtualbox and it's significantly quicker on that too.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the address to binary in network byte order with [inet_pton](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/inet_pton.html). Then set/clear the bits one byte at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Threat the IP lik a 16 bytes array, skip the `masked/8` bytes in the next byte mask the higher `masked%8` bits, set the other ones to `0`

```
int offset=masked/8;
char remmask=0;
int rem = masked%8;
while(rem)
{
   rem--;
   remmask|= 0x80>>rem; //0x80 is the highest bit in a byte set

}
offset++;
(((char*)ipv6)+offset) &= remmask;
while(offset<16)
{
   (((char*)ipv6)+offset=0;
   offset++;
}
```

Wrote the code right here, so it hasn't been tested but I am thinking you could use something like this

Answer (score 0):

this is quick and dirty solution, the source code is below if you want, use it. Warning ! the function assumes the IPv6 address is valid.

```
typedef uint16_t ip6_addr[8];


void ipv6_apply_mask(const char *ip6addr, unsigned int mask, ip6_addr ip6){

    ip6_addr in_ip6;
    inet_pton(PF_INET6, ip6addr, ip6);


    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        in_ip6[i] = ntohs(ip6[i]);
    }

    int index = (int) (mask / 16);
    int residue = mask % 16;

     if(residue == 0 && index == 8)
      return;

     switch(residue){
        case 0:in_ip6[index++] = 0; break;
        case 1:in_ip6[index++]&=0x8000; break;
        case 2:in_ip6[index++]&=0xc000; break;
        case 3:in_ip6[index++]&=0xe000; break;
        case 4:in_ip6[index++]&=0xf000; break;

        case 5:in_ip6[index++]&=0xf800; break;
        case 6:in_ip6[index++]&=0xfc00; break;
        case 7:in_ip6[index++]&=0xfe00; break;
        case 8:in_ip6[index++]&=0xff00; break;

        case  9:in_ip6[index++]&=0xff80; break;
        case 10:in_ip6[index++]&=0xffc0; break;
        case 11:in_ip6[index++]&=0xffe0; break;
        case 12:in_ip6[index++]&=0xfff0; break;

        case 13:in_ip6[index++]&=0xfff8; break;
        case 14:in_ip6[index++]&=0xfffc; break;
        case 15:in_ip6[index++]&=0xfffe; break;
    }

    for (int i = index; i < 8; i++){
       in_ip6[i] = 0;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
       ip6[i] = htons(in_ip6[i]);
    } 

 return;
}
```

Comment: Wow, so convoluted together with ambiguous use of the word "mask".

Answer (score 0):

I searched for this function but the above seem to complex so I wrote my own;

```
// Clear all bits above the prefix
void mask_ipv6(struct in6_addr* a, unsigned prefix)
{
    assert(prefix <= 128);
    unsigned bits_to_clear = 128 - prefix;
    unsigned i = 3;
    while (bits_to_clear >= 32) {
        a->s6_addr32[i] = 0;
        bits_to_clear -= 32;
        i--;
    }
    if (bits_to_clear == 0)
        return;
    uint32_t mask = htonl(~((1 << bits_to_clear) - 1));
    a->s6_addr32[i] &= mask;
}
```

You may of course use a function name more of your liking.